# A finite dimensional algebra associated to the symmetric group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, symmetric-groups

Let $S_n$ be the finite group given as $n \times n$ permutation matrices.

Define for a given field $K$ the algebra $B_n$ as the subalgebra of $M_n(K)$ generated by all permutation matrices of $S_n$. (more generally we can do this for any subgroup of $S_n$ to associate to a finite group such a subalgebra. Often we will just obtain the group algebra, but not always.)

> Question 1: What is the subalgebra $B_n$? Has it been studied before and does it have a name? Can we determine quiver and relations of the basic algebras of the blocks of $B_n$ (over a splitting field of $K$)?

Probably I should know this but I only feel really familiar with quiver algebras.

Here some things that I found out:

-$B_n$ has vector space dimension $(n-1)^2+1$ and is semisimple over a field of characteristic 0. The center of $B_n$ is two dimensional. This implies that the algebra is $M_{n-1}(K) \times K$ since we know two simples that are split over $K$, see the answer of Sasha.

-$B_2$ over a field of characteristic two is isomorphic to $K[x]/(x^2)$ (so it is a non-semisimple Frobenius algebra in this case).

-$B_3$ over a field of characteristic 3 is isomorphic to the the Nakayama with Kupisch series [2,3] (in particular it can have finite non-zero global dimension and thus is not a Frobenius algebra in general).

> Question 2: Is it true that any field $K$ is a splitting field for this algebra? What is the number of simple modules?

Note that if any $K$ is really a splitting field, then the number of simples of the algebra $B$ is given by the vector space dimension of
$B/(rad(B)+[B,B])$, which seems to be 2-dimensional(?).

It would be interesting to see what the algebra for $S_p$ is for the primes $p=5$ and $p=7$ (up to Morita equivalence), but the algebra is not baisc anymore.

Comment: K is always a splitting field for the permutation module of the symmetry group.  In fact every field is a splitting field of KS_n and hence any of its quotient algebras

Comment: In this case the centralizer of S_n is KxK if char K doesn't divide n and is K[x]/(x^2) otherwise. It is just the subalgebra generated by the all ones matrix

Comment: If p does not divide n the algebra is KxM_{n-1}(K).  If p divides n it is the centralizer of the all ones matrix J.  In this case JJ=0 and seems to generate a 1-dimensional square zero ideal and the quotient seems to me M_{n-1}(K) and so there is one simple.

Comment: You're formula for the number of simples I think is for characteristic 0.  In characteristic p you have to mod out by more. See Lemma 7.15 of lam

Comment: Actually not quite sure the quotient is $M_{n-1}(K)$.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I got this formula from Lam, and it should be correct when K is a splitting field.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Note that for $n=p=3$ the algebra is a quiver algebra and thus there should be no quotient $M_2(K)$.

Comment: Yes, I found a larger nilpotent ideal so the radical is bigger  If you take all matrices with constant rows and column sum 0 you get a nilpotent ideal and you can do the dual thing. Maybe these generate the radical.

Comment: I get the quotient by the radical when p divides n is KxM_{n-2}(K)

Comment: I corrected the quiver presentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K$ be a field.  The literal answer has already been given by several people but let me try and get at the algebraic structure and provide a quiver with relations (***see the addition***).  Let $J$ be the $n\times n$ all ones matrix.  Then $J$ centralizes $S_n$ and the centralizer of $J$ consists of all matrices whose rows and columns all sum to some fixed field element $k\in K$.  This has dimension $(n-1)^2+1$ and several people have proved the subalgebra spanned by $S_n$ has this dimension so $B_n$ is the centralizer of $J$.

If the characteristic of $K$ is zero or does not divide $n$, then we can change the basis to consists of $(1,\cdots,1)$ and $e_1-e_i$ with $2\leq i\leq n$ with $e_i$ standard basis vectors.  Then $J$ becomes the elementary matrix $E_{11}$ in this basis and its centralizer is clearly $K\times M_{n-1}(K)$, which can also be seen by representation theory.  This is a split semisimple algebra with two simple modules and there is nothing much to say.

If $K$ has characteristic $p$ dividing $n$, then $J^2=0$ and it is easy to see the Jordan canonical form of $J$ is a $2\times 2$ block and $n-2$ blocks that are $1\times 1$.  In fact the basis $e_1,(1,\ldots, 1), e_i-e_1$ for $2\leq i\leq n-1$ gives the Jordan form with $e_1,(1,\ldots,1)$ giving the $2\times 2$-block.  Thus we can identify $B_n$ with the centralizer of $$J'=N_2\oplus 0_{n-2}$$ where $N_2= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 1&0\end{bmatrix}$.  A more ring theoretic view is the following.

Let $R=K[x]/(x^2)$; its a  self-injective local $K$-algebra and $K$ is the unique simple where $x$ acts by $0$.  Then the centralizer of $J'$ is $\mathrm{End}_R(R\times K^{n-2})$.  I claim the the semisimple quotient here is $K\times M_{n-2}(K)$ and hence there are two simple modules and the algebra $B_n$ is split over $K$.  This is not to difficult to check directly since $R$ is a projective indecomposable $R$-module with simple quotient $K$ and simple socle $K$.  Also note that the radical of $R$ is its socle.  So the radical of $\mathrm{End}_R(R\times K^{n-2})$ is the direct sum of the $1$-dimensional radical of $R$ (viewed as endomorphisms of the first summand $R$), the $n-2$-dimensional space of $R$-module homomorphisms $R\to K^{n-2}$ and the $n-2$-dimensional space of $R$-module homomorphisms $K^{n-2}\to R$ (which all land in the one-dimensional socle=radical).  <strike>From this description it is easy to see that the radical squares to $0$ which means that as soon as you know the quiver, you know the basic algebra.</strike>  The semismple quotient is a copy of $K$ coming from $R/\mathrm{rad}(R)$ and the endomorphisms of the semisimple module $K^{n-2}$, which is $M_{n-2}(K)$. Note that any composition $K^{n-2}\to R\to K^{n-2}$ is zero since the socle of $R$ is its radical. But the compositions $R\to K^{n-2}\to R$ give the elements of $\mathrm{rad}(R)$ and so the radical cubed is zero.

If we view $B_n$ as the centralizer of $J$, then the radical (which has dimension $2n-3$) is spanned by those matrices where each row is a constant vector and each column sums to $0$ and those matrices where each column is a constant vector and each row sums to $0$.  <strike>Hopefully a representation theorist can compute the basic algebra from this description.</strike>

Let me add that when $n=2=p$, this description recovers that $B_2\cong K[x]/(x^2)$ and when $n=3=p$, it recovers that $B_3$ is a basic algebra with semisimple quotient $K\times K$.  <strike>I would guess in general that the basic algebra is $\mathrm{End}_R(R\times K)$ but I am not 100% sure.</strike>

**Added and edited based on corrections by the OP and @JeremyRickard.**  If I am not mistaken, the quiver of $B_n$ when $p\mid n$ and $n>2$ has two vertices $v,w$.  There is one edge from $v$ to $w$, one edge from $w$ to $v$.<strike>and one loop at $v$.  Since its a radical-squared zero split algebra, the quiver presentation for the basic algebra then says that all paths of length $2$ are $0$.  But an expert should check this.</strike>  There is a relation saying the path of length two from $v$ to $v$ is zero. Indeed view $B_n$ as $A=\mathrm{End}_R(R\times K^{n-2})$.  A complete set of orthogonal primitive idempotents are the projection $e$ to $R$ and the $n-2$ projections to $K$, but the latter $n-2$ all give isomorphic projective indecomposables so we just need one of them, say the projection $f$ to the first factor, for the quiver.  Then <strike>since the radical squared is zero,</strike> to compute the quiver we have that $f\mathrm{rad}(A)e=fAe$ is one dimensional and so is $e\mathrm{rad}(A)f=eAf$ since there is a one-dimensional space of homomorphisms $R$ to $K$ and $K$ to $R$.  Also $eAe\cong R$ but $e\mathrm{rad}(R$ is the radical squared as noted above and so $e(\mathrm{rad}(A)/\mathrm{rad}^2(A))e\cong 0$.  On the other hand, $fAf\cong K$ and so $f\mathrm{rad}(A)f=0$. This gives my description of the quiver. That the compositions $K\to R\to K$ are zero but $R\to K\to R$ are not all zero gives the relation.

Comment: I don't think the radical squares to zero, as the composition of $R$-module homomorphisms $R\to K^{n-2}\to R$ may be nonzero.

Comment: So the Jordan canonical form says that the algebra is Morita equivalent to $End_R(R \oplus K)$ for $R=K[x]/(x^2)$ if I understand correctly for $n>2$. This is just the Nakayama algebra with Kupisch series [2,3] (just 2 points 1 and 2 with arrows v from 1 to 2 and w from 2 to 1 with vw=0)or equivalently the first non-trivial Schur algebra. There is no loop.

Comment: @JeremyRickard, you are right.  The radical morphism from R to R is in the radical squared which means no loop and the relation just says $K^{n-2}\to R\to K^{n-2}$ is zero. Glad there are professionals

Comment: I will fix this

Comment: Since this answer also treats the modular case together with the semisimple case, I will accept this.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my quiver @Mare.

Answer (score 15):

For starters one can think about an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. I will only sketch, so there is no need to accept it as an anwer. One can think in terms of representation theory. This $K^n$, viewed as a representation of $S_n$ via permutations, breaks down into the standard representation $V$ (the vectors for which sum of entries is zero) and the trivial representation $W$ (the vectors for which all entries are equal). Then, you can think of the corresponding homomorphism from the group algebra to $M_n (K) \cong End_K (K^n)$. One should recall how the group algebra is the product of matrix algebras parametrized by irreducible representation (Artin-Wederburn theorem..), and realize that there are not a lot of options (there are few two-sided ideals), but to have $End_K (V) \times End_K (W) \cong M_{n-1} (K) \times K$ being isomorphic to the image...

Comment: You don't need algebraically closed because for a 2-transitive group the complement of the trivial module is absolutely irreducible as long as the characteristic doesn't divide the order of the permutation group

Comment: So you are good for any field whose characteristic doesn't  divide n!

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thank you. The second comment I knew, but the first not.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a basis-free description of this algebra (which was already fully described over an arbitrary field in the second part of [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/394610/14094)).

Fix $n\ge 1$. Let $D$ be the line generated by $(1,\dots,1)$, and $H$ the hyperplane $\sum x_i=0$. Let $A_n$ be the algebra of matrices $M$ such that

1. $M$ preserves $D$
2. $M$ preserves $H$
3. $M$ acts by the same scalar on $D$ and on $K^n/H$ (this condition is redundant if $K^n=H\oplus D$, i.e., if $n1_K\neq 0$; however if $n1_K=0$ then $D\subset H$ and this condition removes one dimension)

> I claim the subspace(=subalgebra) $B_n$ generated by permutation matrices equals $A_n$. ($K$ being an arbitrary field)

Note that the dimension of $A_n$ is $(n-1)^2+1$ regardless of vanishing of $n1_K$. We can assume $n\ge 2$ since $n=1$ is trivial.

(Also note that to prove this above result one can clearly assume $K$ algebraically closed, although it's unnecessary.)

---

Proof:

First, $B_n\subset A_n$ is clear. Next, taking differences of pairs of permutations differing by one transposition, one sees that $E_{11}-E_{1k}-E_{\ell 1}+E_{k\ell}\in B_n$ for all $k,\ell\ge 2$. Hence, if $M_0\in A_n$, there exists $M$ in $A_n$ such that $M-M_0\in B_n$ and $M_{\ell k}=0$ for all $k,\ell\ge 2$.

Since $M\in A_n$, there exist $u,v,w\in K$ such that $M_{11}=w$, $M_{1k}=u$ for all $k\ge 2$, $M_{\ell 1}=v$ for all $\ell\ge 2$, and $(n-1)v+w=u$, $(n-1)u+w=v$. In particular $n(u-v)=0$.

If $n1_K\neq 0$, we deduce $u=v$. But in general, the action on $D$ is given by the scalar $v$, while the action on $K^n/H$ is given by the scalar $u$. So $u=v$ follows without restriction on the characteristic of $K$.

Then using transposition matrices, we deduce the existence of a diagonal matrix $M'$ such that $M-M'\in B_n$. Since $M'\in A_n$ is diagonal, all its diagonal entries are equal, and hence $M'\in B_n$. So $M\in B_n$.

---

PS when $n1_K\neq 0$, the result is straightforward from representation theory, since $H\oplus D$ is the isotypic decomposition of the representation and consists of irreducibles (and since one can suppose $K$ algebraically closed).

Comment: This is the centralizer of the all ones matrix and seems cost to Van Name's second answer

Comment: OK.  I didn't know when the edit was made.  Van Name's second answer is any field and was done 12 hrs ago.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg ah, correct, you mean the second part of [the answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/394610/14094).

Comment: Yes that is right.  I somehow suspect there is a representation theoretic reason why this representation is its double centralizer in all characteristics. Maybe it's relevant that if p divides n then J^2=0 where J is the ask ones matrix and so the centralizer algebra is k[x]/(x^2) and this is a uniserial local ring

Comment: Nice argument, but isn't the whole basis-free viewpoint a bit of a distraction? Your three conditions 1, 2 and 3 in the definition of $A_n$ can be restated as "each row has the same sum of entries", "each column has the same sum of entries", and "the sum of entries of any row equals the sum of entries of any column", respectively. From what I'm seeing, it is in this very form that you are using these conditions.

Comment: @darijgrinberg yes, the proof provides nothing new compared to the one given in different terms (which I hadn't noticed then). Whether it's a "distraction" or a more intuitive, or less intuitive statement, is up to the reader. (I've edited to refer to the previous slightly hidden answer by Joseph van Name.)

Answer (score 9):

I claim that if the field is the set of all real numbers or the set of all complex numbers, then $B_{n}$ is the set of all $n\times n$-matrices $A=(a_{i,j})_{i,j}$ where there is some $\lambda$ such that the sum of each row and the sum of each column is $\lambda$ (i.e. $\sum_{i}a_{i,j}=\lambda$ for each $j$ and $\sum_{j}a_{i,j}=\lambda$ for each $i$).

For simplicity, let $K=\mathbb{R}$. The Birkhoff–von Neumann theorem states that the convex closure of $S_{n}$ is precisely the set of all doubly stochastic matrices. Now, since the set of all doubly stochastic matrices is convex closed and closed under multiplication, $B_{n}$ is the set of all matrices of the form $\alpha_{1}A_{1}+\dotsb+\alpha_{r}A_{r}$ where $A_{1},\dotsc,A_{r}$ are doubly stochastic. However, after doing a simplification, the matrices of the form $\alpha_{1}A_{1}+\dotsb+\alpha_{r}A_{r}$ are precisely the matrices of the form $\alpha A-\beta B$ where $A$, $B$ are doubly stochastic and $\alpha,\beta\geq 0$.
Now clearly, every matrix of the form $\alpha A-\beta B$ where $A$, $B$ are doubly stochastic and $\alpha,\beta\geq 0$ is a matrix where the sum of every row and every column is $\alpha-\beta$. Furthermore, if $C$ is an $n\times n$-matrix where the sum of each row and each column is $\lambda$, then let $D=(1/n)_{i,j}$. Then $D$ is a doubly stochastic matrix. Now, there is some $\delta$ where $C+\delta D$ has only positive entries and $C-\delta D$ has only negative entries. Therefore,
$$C=(C+\delta D)/2+(C-\delta D)/2=(\delta D+C)/2-(\delta D-C)/2.$$ Therefore, if
$\alpha=(\delta+\gamma)/2$ and $\beta=(\delta-\gamma)/2$ and
$$A=(\delta D+C)/(2\alpha),B=(\delta D-C)/(2\beta),$$
then $A$, $B$ are doubly stochastic with $C=\alpha A-\beta B$.

**The more general case**

It turns out that for all underlying fields, $B_{n}$ is always equal to the set of all $n\times n$-matrices $A$ where there is some $\lambda$ such that the sum of each row and the sum of each column is equal to $\lambda$. We shall now prove this fact directly without using any facts from representation theory or other result beyond basic linear algebra.

**Lemma:** For all $n$, $\operatorname{Dim}(B_{n})\geq(n-1)^{2}+1$.

**Proof:** This can be proven by induction on $n$. The base case follows from the fact that $\operatorname{Dim}(B_{1})=1$ and $\operatorname{Dim}(B_{2})=2$.
Suppose now that $\operatorname{Dim}(B_{n-1})\geq(n-2)^{2}+1$.

Let $r=(n-2)^{2}+1$. Then let $s_{1},\dotsc,s_{r}\in S_{n-1}$ be linearly independent permutations. Then let $\sigma_{1},\dotsc,\sigma_{r}\in S_{n}$ be the permutations with $\sigma_{i}(j)=s_{i}(j)$ whenever $1\leq i\leq r,1\leq j\leq n-1$.

Let $u_{1},\dotsc,u_{n-1}\in S_{n}$ be arbitrary permutations with
$u_{i}(n)=i,u_{i}(n-1)=n$. Let $v_{1},\dotsc,v_{n-2}\in S_{n}$ be arbitrary permutations with $v_{i}(i)=n$. Then the $(n-1)^{2}+1$ permutations
$$\sigma_{1},\dotsc,\sigma_{r},u_{1},\dotsc,u_{n-1},v_{1},\dotsc,v_{n-2}$$ are all linearly independent, so $\operatorname{Dim}(B_{n})\geq(n-1)^{2}+1$. Q.E.D.

Let $B_{n}^{\sharp}$ be the set of all $n\times n$-matrices $A$ where there is a constant $\lambda$ where the sum of each row and the sum of each column is $\lambda$. Observe that both $B_{n},B_{n}^{\sharp}$ are subalgebras of $M_{n}(K)$. Then $B_{n}\subseteq B_{n}^{\sharp}$. However,
$\operatorname{Dim}(B_{n})\geq (n-1)^{2}+1$ while $\operatorname{Dim}(B_{n}^{\sharp})=(n-1)^{2}+1$. Therefore, $B_{n}=B_{n}^{\sharp}$.

Comment: You can alternatively describe this as the centralizer of the all ones matrix.