# Algebra generated by transformation matrices

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $T_n$ be the full transformation monoid of an $n$-set $N_n$ with elements 1,...,n consisting of all functions $f: N_n \rightarrow N_n$.
We can associate to each function $f$ a matrix $M_f$ in the same way as we associate a permutation matrix to a permutation.

> Question 1: Let $A_n$ be the algebra over the field of complex numbers $K$ generated by all matrices $M_f$ for $f \in T_n$. Is there an explicit description of $A_n$ up to isomorphism? What are quiver and relations for $A_n$?

It seems the dimension of the algebra $A_n$ is given by $n^2-n+1$ and the dimension of the radical of $A_n$ is $n-1$ (so $A_n$ is not semisimple).

The answer for the same question with the symmetric group is discussed here:
[A finite dimensional algebra associated to the symmetric group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394603/a-finite-dimensional-algebra-associated-to-the-symmetric-group)

Now let $E(M_f)$ denote the $2^n \times 2^n$ matrix that is given as the action of $M_f$, a $n \times n$ matrix, on the Grassmann algebra of $K^n$.

> Question 2: Let $B_n$ be the algebra over the complex numbers generated by all matrices $E(M_f)$ for $f \in T_n$. Is there an explicit description of $B_n$ up to isomorphism? What are quiver and relations for $B_n$?

It seems the dimension of the algebra $B_n$ is given by $\binom{2 n-1}{n}$ and $B_n$ is not semisimple again. It seems that a basis of $B_n$ is given by the matrices $E(M_f)$ such that the matrix $M_f$ is totally non-negative (or equivalently $E(M_f)$ having only non-negative entries).

I was able to work out question 2 when taking the permutations instead of all transformations and in this case the answer is very nice: The resulting algebra is isomorphic to the planar hook algebra. But it was not so hard to prove because for the permutation matrices the resulting algebra is semisimple.

For $n=2$, $A_n$ and $B_n$ are both isomorphic to the ring of 2x2 upper triangular matrices over $K$, which might lead to the question whether the algebras $A_n$ and $B_n$ have finite global dimension and what it might be. $A_n$ and $B_n$ seem to be not basic for $n>2$.

It seems that $A_n$ and $B_n$ have one dimensional center, so their quivers should be connected.
By the comment of Benjamin Steinberg, they are quotients of the monoid algebra of $T_n$ and thus their quivers are acyclic and the global dimension is indeed finite.
For $n \leq 5$ the dimensions in this question have been verified with GAP (assuming that the rationals are a splitting field).

Comment: These representations are both projective indecomposable modules for Tn.  See https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10468-016-9597-.  The quiver if T_n is known but but published yet so far as I know but relations are only known up to n=4.  Can one determine the image of an algebra under a projective indecomposable representation from the quiver and relations up to morita equivalence

Comment: I believe A_n is the matrices fixing the all ones for vector assuming you have functions act on the left.

Comment: I'd have to think more on B_n.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Good question. In the semisimple case the image of the representation is the double centraliser which helps alot to calculate the algebra. In the modular case Im not sure how to calculate the image. But what you say should prove that the algebras both have acyclic quiver, so they both have finite global dimension.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg It seems the link you posted does not work.

Comment: Try https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.00959 although this might not be the final version

Comment: $T_n$ has finite global dimension in characteristic 0 and an acyclic quiver.

Comment: So I suspect this must have finite global dimension in characteristic 0

Comment: Sorry the elements of T_n fix the all ones row vector so the algebra just fixes the suspace.

Comment: The radical should be the matrices that annihilate the all ones row vector

Comment: Sorry I just woke up.  When my kid gets to school I'll work this out properly

Comment: I think the radical has codimension $1$ actually

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg It seems the centers are one-dimensional, so that the quivers are connected.

Comment: I'll try to sort this out after coffee and breakfast

Comment: I believe that algebra from your permutation matrices is always the semisimple quotient and that explains the dimensions

Comment: The radical should consist of those matrices whose rows and columns both sum to 0 I think.  I guess that is dimension n-1?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg The connection with the permutation matrices case would be nice. And indeed, it seems $A_n$ has 2 simple modules with a connected quiver and $B_n$ has $n$ simple modules with a connected quiver. So it should be easy to guess what $A_n$ is (but I have problems since it is not basic), but $B_n$ might be more mysterious.

Comment: You can compute it using it is the direct sum of the modules below.  Ill get it later

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg So it seems to me that $A_n$ is just Morita equivalent to the ring of 2x2 upper triangular matrices but $B_n$ is much more interesting.

Comment: I now wrote a complete answer to your question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now that I have worked this out, I will rewrite the answer cleanly. I have deleted the old answer to unclutter things.

The algebra $A_n$ is Morita equivalent to $2\times 2$ upper triangular matrices and the algebra $B_n$ is Morita equivalent to the square-zero algebra with quiver the Dynkin quiver consisting of a straightline path with $n$ vertices.  Moreover, the semisimple quotients of $A_n$ and $B_n$ are the corresponding subalgebras generated by the corresponding representations of $S_n$, asked by the OP in the previous question (linked in the OP).

All of this can be deduced from my paper [The Global Dimension of the full Transformation Monoid (with an Appendix by V. Mazorchuk and B. Steinberg)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10468-016-9597-4)

Let $T_n$ be the full transformation monoid.  Then there is an exact sequence of $\mathbb CT_n$-modules $$0\to \Lambda^k(\mathrm{Aug}(\mathbb C^n))\to \Lambda^k(\mathbb C^n)\to \Lambda^{k-1}(\mathrm{Aug}(\mathbb C^n))\to 0$$ where $\mathrm{Aug}(\mathbb C^n)$ is the subspace of vectors summing up to $0$ for $1\leq k\leq n$.  The modules $\Lambda^k(\mathrm{Aug}(\mathbb C^n)$ are simple $\mathbb CS_n$-modules and hence simple $\mathbb CT_n$-modules.  The middle module $\Lambda^k(\mathbb C_n)$ is a projective indecomposable $\mathbb CT_n$ module (this is proved in my paper, where I write down the primitive idempotent).

For $A_n$ observe it consists of the matrices whose columns all have the same sum, which is $n^2-n+1$-dimensional. The radical consists of those matrices whose rows and columns sum to $0$, which has dimension $n-1$.  It has two simple modules, $\mathbb C$ and $\mathrm{Aug}(\mathbb C^n)$ of dimensions $1$ and $n-1$ and there is a nonsplit exact sequence as above.  Dimension considerations show the quiver has two vertices and one edge.  Hence $A_n$ is Morita equivalent to $2\times 2$ upper triangular matrices.

To explain the $B_n$ case, we can write $1=e+f$ with $ef=fe=0$ and where $e$ is a sum of orthogonal primitive idempotents giving projective indecomposable modules isomorphic to $\Lambda^k(\mathbb C^n)$ for some $0\leq k\leq n$ and $f$ is a sum of orthogonal primitive idempotents giving projective indecomposable modules not isomorphic to any $\Lambda^k(\mathbb C^n)$.  I claim that $B_n\cong e\mathbb CT_ne=\mathbb CT_ne$ and is a hence projective left $\mathbb CT_n$-module.  Thus we can compute $\mathrm{Ext}$ between $B_n$-modules exactly as we do in $\mathbb CT_n$.

Indeed, the above exact sequences show that the projective indecomposable modules $\Lambda^k(\mathbb C^n)$ only have composition factors of the form $\Lambda^j(\mathrm{Aug}(\mathbb C^n))$ with $j\geq k$. Thus $(1-e)\mathbb CT_ne=f\mathbb CT_ne=0$.  But then it follows that $\mathbb CT_ne= (1-e)\mathbb CT_ne\oplus e\mathbb CT_ne=e\mathbb CT_ne$, and so we have a homomorphism $\mathbb CT_n\to e\mathbb CT_ne$ given by $a\mapsto ae$ with kernel $\mathbb CT_nf$ and note that $\mathbb CT_nf$ is the annihilator of $\mathbb CT_ne=e\mathbb CT_ne$.  Since $\Lambda(\mathbb C^n)=\bigoplus_{k=0}^n\Lambda^k(\mathbb C^n)$ is a projective module with the same indecomposable summands as $\mathbb CT_ne$ (but with different multiplicities), it follows that $\Lambda(\mathbb C^n)$ also has annihilator ideal $\mathbb CT_nf$ and so $B_n\cong e\mathbb CT_ne$.

In my paper, I compute $\mathrm{Ext}$ between all the simple $\mathbb CT_n$-modules of the form $\Lambda^k(\mathrm{Aug}(\mathbb C^n))$ and basically $\mathrm{Ext}^q_{\mathbb CT^n}(\Lambda^k(\mathrm{Aug}(\mathbb C^n),\Lambda^j(\mathrm{Aug}(\mathbb C^n))$ is $0$ unless $q=j-k$, in which case it is $1$.

From the above Ext computations, it follows the quiver of $B_n$ is a straightline with $n$-vertices and these are radical-square zero algebras.

Also, since the irreducible representations of $A_n$ and $B_n$ restrict to irreducible representations of $S_n$ it is straightforward that the semisimple quotients are the subalgebras generated by the image of $S_n$ in each algebra (note the above exact sequences split over $S_n$).

For $B_n$, the simple modules $\Lambda_k(\mathrm{Aug}(\mathbb C^n)$  have dimensions $\binom{n-1}{k}$ and hence the semisimple quotient has dimension $\binom{2n-2}{n-1}$.

From the description of the quiver, the dimensions of the simples and the fact that it is radical squared zero, I think you get that the dimension is $\binom{2n-2}{n-1}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{i-1}\binom{n-1}{i}=\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$ using the Vandermonde identity.

**Added.** In fact, I have an unpublished paper (in progress but stalled due to me getting too busy) with Stuart Margolis and Itamar Stein on this algebra and in any event its quiver with relations is the Dold-Kan theorem.  Let $O_n$ be the submonoid of $T_n$ consisting of order-preserving maps.  This is a monoid of size $\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$ and its algebra is precisely $B_n$.  I had not realized before it is a quotient algebra of $\mathbb CT_n$ and also a corner.  The basis described in the OP is the one corresponding to the images of the elements of $O_n$ under this representation since order preserving maps will never turn a wedge negative, while if a map fails to preserve the order of $i<j$, then it will negate $e_i\wedge e_j$.

In our unpublished paper, we observe that Dold-Kan says that the representations of this monoid are the same as chain complexes with $n-1$ maps and $n$ vector spaces (over any field).  We also have a monoid proof of Dold-Kan (which is closely related to a proof of Ross Street, done independently).  Anyway, we observe that  $KO_n$, for any commutative ring $K$, is the endomorphism ring of the chain complex of the $n-1$-simplex over $K$, which over $\mathbb C$ is, of course, $\Lambda(\mathbb C^n)$ equipped with its natural differential.  So now I see that the image of $\mathbb CT_n$ under the natural action of $T_n$ by simplicial maps is the same as the image of $\mathbb CO_n$ in characteristic $0$, and hence $B_n\cong \mathbb CO_n$.  I'm not sure why it took me so long to remember my own work.

So in summary $B_n$ is isomorphic to the monoid algebra $\mathbb CO_n$ and can also be identified with all $\mathbb C$-linear maps on $\Lambda(\mathbb C^n)$ that preserve the grading (i.e., leave each $\Lambda^k(\mathbb C^n)$ invariant) and commute with the differential $$d(e_{i_0}\wedge\cdots \wedge e_{i_k}) = \sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j(e_{i_0}\wedge\cdots\wedge \widehat {e_{i_j}}\wedge\cdots \wedge e_{i_k})$$ (where hat means omit).
So that is the concrete description.

Also this description is valid if you replace $\mathbb C$ by any commutative ring with unit $K$, but now one really needs to use the $O_n$-theory because the $T_n$-theory can break down over nonfields or fields of bad charactersitic.

Comment: But already for $n=2$, the dimension should be 3 and the dimension of the radical should be 1 as the algebra is the ring of 2x2 upper triangular matrices.

Comment: Are you sure on this?  The radical should consists of all matrices sending $\mathbb C^n$ into the radical of the module, which is $\mathrm{Aug}(\mathbb C^n)$ and that seems to be what I describe.

Comment: The computer can calculate the quiver explicitly for n=2 and agrees with the result.

Comment: I just did n=2 by hand and I agree the radical is one dimensional and the semisimple quotient is the algebra from your other question.  So I am not awake yet,

Comment: Very nice observation, that is the key to understand those algebras. For $B_n$ it also seems to be true (at least for small n so far). Here the algebra for the permutation case has dimension $\binom{2n-2}{n-1}$ and the $n$ simples modules have dimension $\binom{n-1}{l}$ for $l=0,1,...,n-1$. I can prove this for the permutation case (where things are semisimple) using the double centraliser theorem.

Comment: @Mare, yes.  I corrected a typo now that I am awake.  The simples are the exterior powers of the $n-1$ dimensional module consisting of sum zero vectors.  But each simple appears twice in this representation except the two extremes so I suppose that will affect the multiplicities.

Comment: So I get for the semisimple quotient $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{i}^2$.  Does that agree with your number?  It seems it does by some identity

Comment: Of course, this is equal to $\binom{2n-2}{n-1}$.

Comment: You don't need to use double centralizers.  It is well known that all these exterior powers of $\mathrm{Aug}(C^n)$ are irreducible symmetric group representations and so the symmetric group answer is clear.  The exact sequence I wrote down is the categorification of the Pascal identity and it splits over $S_n$ but not $T_n$.  The usual proof they are irreducible over $T_n$ is to use that they are irreducible over $S_n$.  All other irreducible reps of $T_n$  do not restrict to irreducible reps of $S_n$.

Comment: I believe that $B_n$ is Mortia equivalent to the radical square zero algebra with quiver a straightline path with n vertices

Comment: Thanks for this great answer!

Comment: I enjoyed thinking about this.  Hopefully now there are no more edits needed and things really work.  I feel there should be an easier proof that the map from $\mathbb CT_n\to B_n$ is a homological epimoprhism.

Comment: Do you have a reference for quiver and relations for the transformation monoid algebra for $n=2,3$? I just found it for $n=4$ in Ringel's article. I noted something strange and need to make sure the relations are correct.

Comment: Thanks. For n<=4  the Coxeter matrix of the algebra is periodic, an extremely rare property. The Coxeter matrix M is given by M=-$C^{-1} C^T$ with $C$ the Cartan matrix. But I guess the Cartan matrix for $n=5$ is not yet available/known to test this for $n=5$?

Comment: I believe the cartan matrix is known explicitly for small n by the people who do representation theory of the category of finite sets.  In general I think this looks like computing plethysms

Comment: Thanks, since you mention that some other MO users work on this, I might as ask this as a seperate question.

Comment: Putcha's paper is https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869397973956

Comment: They haven't published their results so they might not wish to go public

Comment: The quiver for T3 is the dynkin quiver D4 plus an isolated vertex.  There is a relation from one of the length two paths but I don't think the other one is  a relation but I don't recall.  You can check Ringel.  It's a subquiver any the relations are inherited.

Comment: Another funny/strange remark: Ringel's article seems to say that for $n=4$ there are 36 indecomposables, but using his quiver the computer says the algebra has 40 indecomposable. I might check this later by hand who is right.

Comment: Good question.  I'm not sure. Ringel uses stuff above my pay grade.

Comment: I deleted my comment on Putcha's paper because it was the wrong paper. That was the one mentioning the whole quiver is known but not published.  Ill let the people who did this decide if they want to make things  public since I don't know if they do

Comment: I found a much cleaner proof.  It turns out that $B_{n+1}$ is isomorphic to a corner in $\mathbb CT_n$.  Moreover, it is a corner by a right semicentral idempotent and hence is projective as a $\mathbb CT_n$-module.  So I don't need the quasi-hereditary algebra stuff.

Comment: @Mare, are you sure about the dimension of $B_n$ being $\binom{2n-1}{n}$.  I get $\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$ and from this I can prove it is a monoid algebra because I have an published paper that gives a submonoid of $T_n$ whose algebra has this quiver and that dimension and the same simples and projective indecomposables etc.

Comment: Those are the same numbers, or?

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Mathoverflow early in the morning or late at night is dangerous. .   Am I correct your basis corresponds to the f which preserve the standard order on 1,…,n?

Comment: Notice the Cauchy completion of O_n is the truncated simplex category so you immediately get the quiver with relations from Dold-Kan and I essentially have a different version of our unpublished proof in characteristic 0 using facts about Tn instead of On.

Comment: That should be correct.

Comment: Well, it took me more or less from 6am until 11pm, but I think I now know exactly what is going on with your question and it basically runs through two of my papers (one unpublished and joint), plus one additional observation I was unaware of.

Comment: The last part is very beautiful although the final quiver algebra for $B_n$ is much simpler than expected.

Comment: The final description I should have added also that these are the maps preserving the grading (or degree).  Yes, this Morita description is equivalent to Dold-Kan (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dold%E2%80%93Kan_correspondence) over C.

Comment: When we get around to finishing this unpublished paper is it ok if I add this description of COn?  I think it is a cute observation that I sort of knew but hadn’t formulated precisely.   I had recognized our arguments were similar to the Tn paper but we didn’t need characteristic 0 because we were using order preserving maps and we didn’t rely on Sn theory.

Comment: Yes, that is ok.

Comment: So I guess if we work over any commutative ring with unit $K$, it is still the case that the image of $KT_n$ under the action on $\Lambda(K^n)$ is $KO_n$ with the basis you described because $T_n$ acts by degree preserving maps commuting with the differential and we proved in our unpublished paper that $KO_n$ is the full algebra of such maps.  I just can no longer use my first argument based on $KT_n$-representation theory to prove it.  In particular, the quiver doesn't depend on the field in the case of a field.  Anyway, thanks for giving me something fun to think about today.